# In French, how do you allude to someone's 'bizarre' taste with euphemism?

Tags: expressions

> Il a toujours eu des goûts tr**èee**s **particuliers**.

Today in conversation with my colleagues, I wanted to euphemistically allude to someone's bizarre taste in fashion, sugar-coating the idea of "there's no accounting for tastes".

I used the adjective "particulier" after a somewhat prolonged vowel sound: "trèees", but I'm not sure if "particulier" sounds euphemistic enough. In any case, I'm looking for other phrasings that get the job done.

Comment: If you want to convey that the vowel sound is prolonged, write the vowel multiple times: *trééés*.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, do you mean "trèèès"?

Comment: Oops, yes. (I don't think there's a canonical French equivalent for “Skitt's law”. It isn't exactly a case of *l'arroseur arrosé*, but close.)

Comment: @Gilles on pourrait lancer "loi de MuphRy" comme expression "franssaize" ;-)

Comment: I often use "interesting" and "special" as [thinly veiled] euphemisms for "bizarre" in English, but as far as I can tell, while using "avoir des goûts [disons ...] intéressants" **might** work in French, I'd avoid using ["avoir des goûts spéciaux"](https://books.google.com/books?id=-MaHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA489&dq=%22avoir+des+go%C3%BBts+sp%C3%A9ciaux%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcgszbrPbbAhUmqlkKHc48CEQQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22avoir%20des%20go%C3%BBts%20sp%C3%A9ciaux%22&f=false) except where it would fit the particular job that one needs to get done!

Comment: On peut aussi utiliser _atypique_ ou _singulier_ à la place de _particulier_

Answer (score 6):

I would say

> Il a toujours eu des goûts un peu particuliers.

You can say “*très*” instead of “*un peu*”, but then the sentence is emphatic, not euphemistic.

Another way to indicate that someone has eccentric tastes is

> Il a toujours eu des goûts bien à lui.

(Here “*bien*” means “very”, not “good”: his tastes are very much his own.)

Answer (score 3):

Your suggestion of "particulier" is a good one. You could also use "des goûts très originaux".

If you want a typical expression (similar to "there is no accounting for tastes"), you could use :

```
Les goûts et les couleurs, ça ne se discute/dispute pas.
```

or

```
Des goûts et les couleurs, on ne discute pas.
```

This means that his tastes are not like yours, but this is not something that you could argue about.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, you could also drop the second part if you are talking to native speakers.

```
Comme quoi, les goûts et les couleurs...
```

Comment: Dropping the second half packs more punch, I take it? Something like: "Enfin bon, les goûts et les couleurs, hein ?"

Comment: yes, you could say that